# About facet in Azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have several questions about Azure search facet feature.

1. Does Azure search support metrics facet, just like the metric aggregation in Elasticsearch? For example, I have a Price field, and I want to aggreage the price for average price of all products.
2. How to implement the sub facet, that is, the facet on other facets. 
   For example, we have two facet fields, ProductType and Price, instead of aggregate price range on whole documents, we want aggregate price range on each ProductType.
3. Is top hits facet supported? Just like Elasticsearch top_hit aggregation, we want get top hits documents for each faceted buckets.

Answer (score 1):

The only facets supported in Azure Search are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#facetstring-zero-or-more) and they don't include what would be an equivalent of metrics aggregations in ElasticSearch including the top_hits aggregation. Nesting facets (hierarchical facets) is also not supported with a single query. Please vote for this capability [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/7035293-support-hierarchical-facets). [This article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/onsearch/2015/09/09/multi-level-taxonomy-facets-in-azure-search/) describes a way some users work around this limitation.